# ios - xcode - 'autoplay' within webView load causes player to load over app

Tags: ios, xcode

Please excuse my limited knowledge of xcode/ios development. I'm picking up a project and following a change of URL that loads in a webView, when the content loads the URL (which contains a live streaming link that autoplays on load) as follows in the HTML of the page:

```
<video id='video_tag' width='1000' height='41' controls="" autoplay="">
<source src='http://domain:ip/;stream.mp3/playlist.m3u8' type='video/mp4'>
<a href='http://domain:ip/;stream.mp3' id='android_firefox' style='display:none;'>Watch this stream over RTSP for Android Mozilla</a><script>if (navigator.userAgent.match(/Android/i) && navigator.userAgent.match(/Firefox/i)) {
document.getElementById('android_firefox').style.display='';document.getElementById('video_tag').style.display = 'none';}
jwplayer.key='xxxxxxxxxxx=';
jwplayer('primcast.com').setup(
{playlist: [{sources:[{file:'http://domain:ip/;stream.mp3'},
{file:'http://domain:ip/;stream.mp3/playlist.m3u8'}]}],
     logo: {file: ''},width:1000,height:41,stretching:'undefined',autostart:true,fallback:false,primary:'HTML5',repeat:true});
</script></source></video>
```

When the App loads this in the webView, the screen goes blank, but if you touch the screen, it is trying to play the audio above the app. There is a 'x' in the top right of the screen, which if pressed, returns to the webView App correctly with the following in the debugger:

```
[34780:2737829] WF: _WebFilterIsActive returning: NO
[34780:2737715] [] <<<< AVOutputDeviceDiscoverySession (FigRouteDiscoverer) >>>> -[AVFigRouteDiscovererOutputDeviceDiscoverySessionImpl outputDeviceDiscoverySessionDidChangeDiscoveryMode:]: Setting device discovery mode to DiscoveryMode_Presence (client: My App)
[34780:2737715] [framework] CUICatalog: Invalid asset name supplied: '(null)'
[34780:2737715] [framework] CUICatalog: Invalid asset name supplied: '(null)'
[34780:2737715] [] <<<< AVOutputDeviceDiscoverySession (FigRouteDiscoverer) >>>> -[AVFigRouteDiscovererOutputDeviceDiscoverySessionImpl outputDeviceDiscoverySessionDidChangeDiscoveryMode:]: Setting device discovery mode to DiscoveryMode_None (client: My App)
[34780:2737715] [] <<<< AVOutputDeviceDiscoverySession (FigRouteDiscoverer) >>>> -[AVFigRouteDiscovererOutputDeviceDiscoverySessionImpl outputDeviceDiscoverySessionDidChangeDiscoveryMode:]: Setting device discovery mode to DiscoveryMode_None (client: My App)
[34780:2737715] [framework] CUICatalog: Invalid asset name supplied: '(null)'
[34780:2737715] [framework] CUICatalog: Invalid asset name supplied: '(null)'
[34780:2737715] [] <<<< AVOutputDeviceDiscoverySession (FigRouteDiscoverer) >>>> -[AVFigRouteDiscovererOutputDeviceDiscoverySessionImpl outputDeviceDiscoverySessionDidChangeDiscoveryMode:]: Setting device discovery mode to DiscoveryMode_Presence (client: My App)
[34780:2737715] [] <<<< AVOutputDeviceDiscoverySession (FigRouteDiscoverer) >>>> -[AVFigRouteDiscovererOutputDeviceDiscoverySessionImpl outputDeviceDiscoverySessionDidChangeDiscoveryMode:]: Setting device discovery mode to DiscoveryMode_None (client: My App)
```

From what I understand, it is the autoplay and `<video>` tag that is causing this behaviour?

I guess, my question is, is it at all possible for me to stop this behaviour at all from within the App by bypassing that part of the code that makes the App try and load the player, if yes, how?

The user does not want to take away the autoplay feature on the website, so the ideal solution would be to stop it in-app.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve this adding these lines

```
Webview.mediaPlaybackRequiresUserAction=TRUE;
Webview.mediaPlaybackRequiresUserAction = true;
Webview.allowsInlineMediaPlayback = false;
```